# conditional rendered f:selectItem possible problems

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, selectonemenu, rendered-attribute

I have a page with several `h:selectOneMenu` or `p:selectOneMenu` and I want to use the same page for editing and adding data. 
When I will edit data I need `f:selectItem`. I know that this component doesn't have attribute rendered. And I read that I can use `<c:if>`.

Ok. For example, if I write

```html
<p:selectOneMenu rendered="#{not empty bean.id}"
    value="#{bean.selectedId}">
    <c:if test="${editableBean != null}">
        <f:selectItem itemLable="#{editableBean.name} itemValue=#{editableBean.id} />
    </c:if>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listItems}" var="item"
        itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.id}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Will it works without any problems in primefaces and with ajax listeners?

Comment: @GaborSch if you don't know how JSF works, please refrain to add comments that doesn't help OP to address a good solution.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I know how JSF works, but I want the OP to try before he asks. BTW, the answer is `Yes` or `No`, so this is not a good question.

Comment: @GaborSch if you know how JSF works, then you already know that OP's suggestion is not the best solution =\, and if you really know, please provide an answer :).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Let's not fight on this. OP wants to know whether a solution (piece of code) works or not. To decide this question, someone has to try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy solution (but with poor performance) will be to have a `boolean editMode` attribute in your managed bean to enable/disable the components. Basic example:

```html
<p:selectOneMenu rendered="#{not empty bean.id}" disabled="#{bean.editMode}"
    value="#{bean.selectedId}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listItems}" var="item"
        itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.id}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

In your bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private int id;
    private boolean editMode;
    //other attributes...
    //getters and setters...

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //a way to know if the bean it's in edit mode
        editMode = (id != 0);
    }
}
```

This solution will have poor performance because every `<p:selectOneMenu>` will have to load all the data and then select the actual value, but it will do what you want. Another option will be to use this attribute for the `rendered` property of `<p:selectOneMenu>` and for an `<h:inputText disabled="true" readonly="true" />` (or maybe `<h:outputText />`). Another basic sample:

```
<p:selectOneMenu rendered="#{not empty bean.id && not bean.editMode}"
    value="#{bean.selectedId}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listItems}" var="item"
        itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.id}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<h:inputText rendered="#{bean.editMode}" value="{bean.selectedText}"
    disabled="true" readonly="true" />
```

Comment: mayb i dint understand the question properly but can't we just change the backing collection which is wired with `f:selectItems` conditionally ?

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR that could be another solution but I tend to have almost all the list for `<f:selectItems>` in an `@ApplicationScoped` managed bean and updating the values from time to time instead of getting the list values on each request.